# Will DFP serve an ad which doesn't satisfy custom targeting?

Tags: google-dfp

In a typical Header Bidding system, we generally target line items using a bid price key value pair. Now many direct or guaranteed line items do not have such key value pair. Do they and if yes how they compete with the targeted line item?

Answer (score 0):

Yes other line items would participate in the auction along with line items targeted to header bidding custom key values.

From DFP's perspective your HB line items are no different from the regular ones hence the auction would take place according to common rules:

https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1143651?hl=en
     ...

> 3. The ad server selects the best line item to serve by scanning the list of eligible matching line items, starting with highest priority
>      and working down until it identifies the best candidate line item.
>      If dynamic allocation is enabled, DFP checks to see if a remnant line
>      item can be served without affecting the delivery goals or pacing for
>      the candidate line item. This increases overall yield for the network
>      without increasing the risk of underdelivery.
> 4. The ad server selects the best creative from within the selected line item.
> 5. The ad server serves the creative to the user.